# MySQL: ternary IF(expr, if, else) with CAST

Tags: mysql

why does

```
SELECT IF(mytimestamp IS NULL, NULL, mytimestamp) FROM fixed_date
```

return NULL (as expected),
but

```
SELECT IF(mytimestamp IS NULL, NULL, CAST(mytimestamp AS char)) FROM fixed_date
```

returns '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?

I need the latter one returning me NULL, that's why I'm asking. So how do I do that?

Edit: mytimestamp is a TIMESTAMP. I would have expected both statements to return null, if mytimestamp = NULL. In my case, the timestamp must be converted to CHAR, because my frontend expects it this way (it's a little more complicated, actually).

**Solution**: I had set 'mytimestamp' to NOT NULLable (and DEFAULTint to '0000-00-00...'. Setting it to NULLable, it works as expected (returning NULL). Sorry, my fault.

Thanks,
Bernhard

Comment: Its working the way it should.  Once you cast a 0 date to char, it can not be null.

Comment: But he checks against NULL before, so it's not the cast.

Comment: What is TYPE of `mytimestamp`? Is it a TIMESTAMP?

Comment: TYPE is TIMESTAMP. As it returns in '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Comment: What are your expected output? NULL and? Why are you casting to char?

Comment: Is (NULL) set for your specific TIMESTAMP in database?

Comment: Reproduced your case in way, that I emptied TIMESTAMP value for a field and saved changes. On save, it default to '0000-00-00 00:00:00', thus its not a (NULL) value being returned. On setting (NULL), the query is working fine.

Comment: Thanks, Parkash. Actually this was my fault. I set 'mytimestamp' to NULLable, the default value was automatically set to '0000-00-00...'. Setting 'mytimestamp' to NULLable, it works fine.